# Apple pay is it mandatory on native mobile app?

Tags: ios, native, payment

I built an e-commerce app. But I've just implemented Stripe Payment without implementing Apple Pay.

Before I put it in production, my question is:

Is it mandatory to have an apple pay payment method on an iOS App?

Is there any chance that I will be refused from the App Store?

Comment: Explaining apple guidelines is off-topic here.

Comment: What are you selling?  Digital goods or services delivered in the app or physical goods or services delivered outside the app?  The former requires in-app-purchase (not Apple Pay). The latter cannot use in-app purchase.  You can use any other payment method you like including ApplePay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand no you don't need Apple Pay to be on the App Store. Though you do need a Mac go to https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines for the full guidelines on review.